# A problem on symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

I encountered the following problem which I believe contains a mistake.

Denote $E(t) = \sum \limits s_kt^k$ and $H(t) = \sum h_kt^k$, where $s_i$ are the elementary symmetric functions of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and $h_k$ I don't know what.

1) $\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 + x_it) = E(t)$ -- it's easy.

2) $\prod \limits_{i = 1}^n (1 + x_it)^{-1} = H(t)$ -- it clearly can't be true.

I think that $H(t)$ is actually a formal power series and not a polynomial and there should be a minus sign inside the brackets ( $1 - x_it)$. And I think that $h_k = \sum \limits_{i_1 + i_2 \ldots i_n = k} x_1^{i_1} \ldots x_n^{i_n}$

Then follows

3) $E(-t)H(t) = 1$ which confirms my suspicion about the minus sign.

All in all, my questions are:

1) Does what I wrote make sense?

2) Does this $H(t)$ thing have a name?

3) If it does and it is some standard thing, does my calculation coincide with its definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the minus sign. $h_k$ is the complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial of degree $k$, which as you wrote is the sum of all monomials of degree $k$ in the variables. $H(t)$ is a formal power series because there are infinitely many nonzero $h_k$.

$s_k$ is a very disturbing choice of notation for the elementary symmetric polynomial in my opinion. It makes me wonder what they call Schur polynomials (though they may just not come up).

Comment: They called it $e_k$. I wrote $s_k$ because I am used to this notation (by Dummit, Foot).

Comment: @Vladislav $e_k$ is the standard notation. Schur polynomials are written as $s_\lambda$ generally, and I think that's pretty good notation for them. It's true that elementary symmetric polynomials are also Schur polynomials, but they're not $s_{(k)}$, they're $s_{(1^k)}$, so it would be pretty confusing.